# maven dependency not resolved

Tags: java, maven

I have the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ant</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.5-osgi</version>
    </dependency>
```

it is not available in the maven central repository.
which mirror can I choose to resolve it properly  (install locally and deploy to our internal repository)?

UPDATE
I see from the answers that i need to add some details.
This dependency is not explicitly set in any of our poms. When calling maven install it happens that it fails cause cannot find it. I post the full stack:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXXXX-functional-test: Could not resolve
    dependencies for project XXXXXX-functional-test:jar:2.16.1: Failed to collect dependencies
    for [org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.7.2 (test), sahi:sahi:jar:3.5 (test), 
    org.easyb:easyb-core:jar:1.1 (test), org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.1 (test), 
    commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4 (test), org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.8 (compile), 
    org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-sftp:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE (compile), 
    org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE (compile), 
    org.springframework:spring-dao:jar:1.2.5 (test), junit:junit:jar:4.8.2 (test), 
    org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5 (test), mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.13 (provided), 
    com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.1.0 (provided), log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16 (compile), 
    org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (test), org.springframework:spring-
    context-support:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE (compile), org.springframework.integration:spring-
    integration-mail:jar:2.0.0.M4 (compile), org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE 
    (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for ant:ant:jar:1.6.5-osgi: Could not transfer 
    artifact ant:ant:pom:1.6.5-osgi from/to nexus 
    (http://ournexusaddress:8081/nexus/content/groups/public): Checksum validation failed, could 
    not read expected checksum: C:\Users\andrea\.m2\repository\ant\ant\1.6.5-osgi\ant-1.6.5-
    osgi.pom.sha1.tmp56e90fe6eda74ac3 (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]
```

At this point I run mvn with options -e -X and:

```
    Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed,        
     could not read expected checksum: C:\Users\andrea\.m2\repository\ant\ant\1.6.5-osgi\ant-
    1.6.5-osgi.pom.sha1.tmp56e90fe6eda74ac3 (The system cannot find the file 
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.verifyChecksum(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:714)

at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:618)
... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\andrea\.m2\repository\ant\ant\1.6.5-osgi\ant-1.6.5-osgi.pom.sha1.tmp56e90fe6eda74ac3 (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.ChecksumUtils.read(ChecksumUtils.java:47)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.verifyChecksum(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:710)
    ... 5 more

[ERROR] 
[ERROR]
```

For this reason I have tried to see if I can find the pom given on the top of the question. I also add the explicitly called dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>sahi</groupId>
        <artifactId>sahi</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easyb</groupId>
        <artifactId>easyb-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Currently as a workaround, I found in a local maven repository of one of our CI build server (the build was green:-) ) an uncorrupted version. of 1.6.5-osgi  and i will upload it to nexus.

Answer (score 1):

A mirror is available at http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/

---

Or Try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant.osgi</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Or

latest version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Apache ivy maven config

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ivy</groupId>
    <artifactId>ivy</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I really need 1.6.5-osgi. I explain it in the question now updated

Comment: I have added a mirror link, also kindly try with artifact id <artifactId>ant.osgi</artifactId>. Also look like that ant OSGI support is moved to apache ivy. Just check, if it is so.

Comment: the repo i already tried. Nothhing. I tested the validity also in intellij-settings-mave-add repository (which is like adding to settings) and no reply. The other options cannot be ok. in the repo should appear ant/ant/1.6.5-osgi

Comment: The mirror has pom of 1.3k and jar of 956 kb .. and i am able to download it manually! What issue you are facing with this?

Comment: it is not working as a mirror. Try to put it in settings.xml and it doesn't connect. If it works for you, let me know. perhaps i am just doing something wrong (I doubt but I hope....).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37358/discussion-between-blackbird014-and-gyan)

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ant</groupId>
  <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.5-osgi</version>
  <type>pom</type>// remove this 
</dependency>
```

And try

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>ant</groupId>
  <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.5</version>      
</dependency>
```

Comment: I really need 1.6.5-osgi. I explain it in the question now updated